# Exceptions in method declarations. JAXB

Tags: java, web-services, jaxb, cxf

Suppose I have such exceptions hierarchy:

```
public class A extends RuntimeException {
...
}

public class B extends A {
...
}
```

In the web service interface there is a method:

```
public void aa() throws A;
```

Implementation of this method can throw either exception `A` or exception `B`, but while deploying to tomcat cxf publishes wsdl only with `A` exception declaration.

I have tried to use `@XmlRootElement` on both classes, `@XmlType` on both classes, `@XmlRootElement` on parent class, `@XmlRootElement` with `@XmlSeeAlso` on parent class, but published wsdl doesn't have `B` exception declaration. Also I have written a test that uses that wsdl and test gets only A exception however I've emulated both types of exceptions. How can I get child exception in wsdl declaration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to list both `A` and `B` as possible exceptions thrown from `aa`, otherwise jaxb has no means to know that you might throw exceptions of derived classes.  Try:

```
public void aa() throws A, B;
```

Comment: It is not very comfortable way to declare the hierarchy of exception in `throws`. Maybe it can be done by writing some interceptor? I mean, if method has declaration of exception `A`(for example) then interceptor has to add all exception that extends exception `A`

Comment: You could certainly write an inceptor, but JAXBContext should already do that for you as long as it knows about the derived classes as well (which @XmlSeeAlso should have done for you).  You might want to take a look at some other techniques as well: [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6469599/using-derived-classes-when-marshelling-with-jaxb), [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8318231/xmlseealso-alternative), [3](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/11/jaxb-and-inheritance-using-substitution.html), [4](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/11/jaxb-and-inheritance-moxy-extension.html)